# How to pass a format! string and format! arguments to a Rust macro that creates a function?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm making a web API client. I want to create functions that correspond to the available API endpoints.

In some cases, the URL is always the same. Then, manually calling the API looks something like this:

```rust
let things_list_url = "https://example.com/api/things/list";
let things_list: Vec<SomeThing> = make_request(GET, thing_list_url).into();
```

The macro I'm using for this looks like:

```rust
macro_rules! api_request {
  ($name: ident, $method: ident, $path: expr, $return_type: ty) => {
    pub fn $name() -> $return_type {
      let action_url = format!("https://example.com/api{}", $path);
      let action_result = make_request($method, action_url);
      action_result.into()
    }
  };
}

api_request!(get_things_list, GET, "/things/list", Vec<SomeThing>);

fn main() {
  println!("{:?}", get_things_list());
}
```

A similar pattern works for when the API call has a body, as long as the URL remains the same.

Some other endpoints have parameters in their URL. Manually calling them looks like:

```rust
let thing = SomeThing { id: 123, ...};
let thing_status_url = format!("https://example.com/api/things/{}/status", thing.id);
let thing_status: SomeThingStatus = make_request(GET, thing_status_url).into();
```

However, my attempt at making a macro for this does not work. For simplicity, let's assume there is only one argument to the `format!` call:

```rust
macro_rules! api_request_with_path {
  ($name: ident, $method: ident, $request_type: ty, $return_type: ty, $path_format_string: expr, $path_format_arg: expr) => {
    pub fn $name(
      arg: $request_type
    ) -> $return_type {
      let action_url_fragment = format!($path_format_string, $path_format_arg);
      let action_url = format!("https://example.com/api{}", action_url_fragment);
      let action_result = make_request($method, action_url);
      action_result.into()
    }
  };
}

api_request_with_path!(get_thing_status, GET, SomeThing, SomeThingStatus, "things/{}/status", arg.id);
```

This fails, because I'm passing an expression that includes `arg` -- the argument to the generated function -- but the `arg` does not exist at the scope where the macro call is.
How can I provide the macro with a way to turn the argument of type `$request_type` into a URL string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can pass a partial expression in as a raw token sequence
2. You should probably accept a literal for the format string instead of an expression

```rust
macro_rules! api_request_with_path {
  ($name: ident, $method: ident, $request_type: ty, $return_type: ty, $path_format_string: literal, $($path_format_arg: tt)*) => {
    pub fn $name(
      arg: $request_type
    ) -> $return_type {
      let action_url_fragment = format!($path_format_string, arg $($path_format_arg)*);
      let action_url = format!("https://example.com/api{}", action_url_fragment);
      let action_result = make_request($method, action_url);
      action_result.into()
    }
  };
}

api_request_with_path!(get_thing_status, GET, SomeThing, SomeThingStatus, "things/{}/status", .id);
```

If that isn't flexible enough, you can accept a closure instead

```rust
macro_rules! api_request_with_path {
  ($name: ident, $method: ident, $request_type: ty, $return_type: ty, $path_format_string: literal, $path_format_arg: expr) => {
    pub fn $name(
      arg: $request_type
    ) -> $return_type {
      let action_url_fragment = format!($path_format_string, $path_format_arg(arg));
      let action_url = format!("https://example.com/api{}", action_url_fragment);
      let action_result = make_request($method, action_url);
      action_result.into()
    }
  };
}

api_request_with_path!(get_thing_status, GET, SomeThing, SomeThingStatus, "things/{}/status", |arg: SomeThing| arg.id);
```

If you want to avoid needing to specify the closure parameter type, you can tokenize the closure:

```rust
macro_rules! api_request_with_path {
  ($name: ident, $method: ident, $request_type: ty, $return_type: ty, $path_format_string: literal, |$path_format_arg_var: ident| $($path_format_arg: tt)*) => {
    pub fn $name(
      arg: $request_type
    ) -> $return_type {
      let closure = |$path_format_arg_var: $request_type| $($path_format_arg)*;

      let action_url_fragment = format!($path_format_string, closure(arg));
      let action_url = format!("https://example.com/api{}", action_url_fragment);
      let action_result = make_request($method, action_url);
      action_result.into()
    }
  };
}

api_request_with_path!(get_thing_status, GET, SomeThing, SomeThingStatus, "things/{}/status", |arg| arg.id);
```